# Admob ad stuck with "You can skip this ad in 5s"

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, interstitial

I am using Admob for my iOS app. It has been going fine, but the full screen ad "GADInterstitial" sometimes produces a black screen with text "You can skip this ad in 5s". It stays the same with black screen and there is no option to skip. Any idea what could be the problem?

P.S. Access to Youtube is blocked here so is that the problem if it is a video ad?

I can see animated ads perfectly (probably gif) but sometimes this black screen gets stuck which requires minimizing the app and then switching back.

I have simply followed the code provided [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#ios)

```
- (void) showAd
{
    GADInterstitial *interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    interstitial_.adUnitID = MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID;
    [interstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}

- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
{
    [interstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would assume that the timer isn't starting until it can display the video (which never happens because it's blocked).

Can we see some of your code?

Comment: I have simply followed the instructions from Admob. Code added in question

Comment: run it through charles proxy and see what is going on... from a network point of view

Comment: Tried it but this is really difficult to reproduce. The ads were fine using proxy, but I never came across any video ad. Even without proxy it works fine mostly, but this black screen just comes out of nowhere.

Comment: Happens to some of my users too, I'll try to find out if they have you tube blocked